# How to create regex with replace spaces and add spaces between semicolons

Tags: javascript, regex

how to create a regex that replaces a space with an underscore and adds spaces between semicolons?

Replacing a space with a underscore in the entire text can be solved:

```
data.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

But how to solve the situation with semicolons at the same time? The point is that I have a text file that separates individual texts with an underscore. If it does not contain any data, it simply continues in the next semicolons:

```
data;data;;data;;;data
```

I need it to add a blank space between the semicolons in each case. The problem is that the number of semicolons is irregular and I always need to add a space:

```
data;data; ;data; ; ;data
```

There are more than 10,000 such lines in the text file. Is there a solution for my case?

```js
const data = "red;;I WW2;123;;;error;more;;blue;;;;123;I love you";

const replaceData = data.replace(/ /g, "_");

/*
//
//This is not a solution for me, as the number of semicolons is not always the same. And I also can't combine this regex into one.
//
//const replaceData2 = data.replace(/;;/g, "; ;");
*/

console.log(replaceData);
```

The result should be like this:

```
red; ;I_WW2;123; ; ;error;more; ;blue; ; ; ;123;I_love_you
```

Thanks

Comment: `const replaceData2 = data.replace(/;(?=;)/g, "; ");`

Comment: First solution dont work for me. But second is ok. Is there any way to combine it into 1 regex? (I mean underscores, but also semicolons).

Comment: Why? You can use a callback to do it based on one regex, but there is no gain...

Comment: Isn't it faster if the text really has more than 10,000 lines?

Comment: No, because the callback execution will kill what you gain. But you can try it out on your case and decide...

Answer (score 2):

You can call `.replace` twice:

```js
const data = "red;;I WW2;123;;;error;more;;blue;;;;123;I love you";
var repl = data.replace(/ +/g, "_").replace(/;(?=;)/g, "$& ");

console.log(repl);
```

But make sure to replace spaces with `_` before inserting spaces between `;`s.

- `.replace(/ +/g, "_")`: Replace 1+ spaces with `_`
- `.replace(/;(?=;)/g, "$& ")`: Insert space between 2 adjacent semicolons

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with one regex, it can be done with a callback argument, but this will also cost execution time. Like I wrote in comments, it may turn out to be better to stick with 2 `replace` calls. Just see how it performs in your environment, and on your data.

Here is how it would work with callback:

```js
const data = "red;;I WW2;123;;;error;more;;blue;;;;123;I love you";

const result = data.replace(/ |(?<=;)(?=;)/g, m => " _"[m.length]);

console.log(result);
```

The regex has a zero-length match between two semi-colons, so when it matches that, `m` will be the empty string (in the callback). So the size of `m` can be used to distinguish the two cases, and `length` can then serve to select the replacement character (either a space or an underscore).

Comment: This is really clever. Needed some time to puzzle out how this `" _"[m.length])` thing works.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you to get your desire output.

1. Positive Lookbehind (?<=;)
2. Positive Lookahead (?=;)

and we replace it with `" "` `space`.

```js
const data = "red;;I WW2;123;;;error;more;;blue;;;;123;I love you";
const replaceData = data.replace(/(?<=;)(?=;)/g, " ");
console.log(replaceData)
```

Comment: Expected output has `_`s

Comment: @anubhava @TheDarback already mention in question he solve `_` problem already.